# Jquery doesn't react to Jquery created text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

What I'm trying to do is add elements to a list at the press of a button, but then be able to delete any item, again, at the press of a button. Here is a minimal working example of what I mean:

```js
$('.delete-item').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().text("DELETED")
})

$('button').click(function() {
  $('ul').append(`<li>Appended item <a class="delete-item" href="#">Delete item</a></li>`)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>List item 1 <a class="delete-item" href="#">Delete item</a></li>
  <li>List item 2 <a class="delete-item" href="#">Delete item</a></li>
</ul>

<button type="button">Add item</button>
```

Here, you can add items to the unordered list and "delete" already existing items, now, what happens is that you can delete the premade items just fine, but if you try to delete an appended item, for whatever reason, you simply can't. 
How is this fixed? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('.delete-item').click(...)` attaches the event listener to existing items only. Use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) like so:

```
$("ul").on("click", ".delete-item", function() {
    $(this).parent().text("DELETED")
});
```

With event delegation you attach the event listener to an ancestor that already exists in the DOM (here the `<ul>` element) and watch for the event on the descendants whether they already exist or added dynamically.

**Demo:**

```js
$("ul").on("click", ".delete-item", function() {
  $(this).parent().text("DELETED")
});

$("button").click(function() {
  $("ul").append(`<li>Appended item <a class="delete-item" href="#">Delete item</a></li>`)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>List item 1 <a class="delete-item" href="#">Delete item</a></li>
  <li>List item 2 <a class="delete-item" href="#">Delete item</a></li>
</ul>

<button type="button">Add item</button>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I never heard of "event delegation" before.

Comment: @PrograMartin You are welcome! And yeah, event delegation is a life saver in situations like this. Happy coding :)